# .htaccess redirection does not work for https:// to https://www

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, apache2

I currently have a website built on Angular and hosted on Apache2 on a Ubuntu server and recently changed the SSL certificate. I keep getting 'NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID' if I go to `https://example.com/public/home` but no error when going to `https://www.example.com/public/home`.

One strange thing is if I write the URL as `https://example.com/public/home/`, it properly redirects to `https://www.example.com/public/home`. Also, going to `example.com` redirects to the correct one.

I've shared below my current htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
# Don't rewrite files or directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]

#http to https
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

What should I change for the correct redirection for https to https www?

Comment: you need an SSL certificate with both names: example.com and www.example.com.

Comment: In addition to the above comment (although it is strange that you don't appear to get the cert error when simply appending a slash to the URL-path?)... It doesn't look like the `.htaccess` file you posted is doing anything, you state that it "properly redirects to `https://www.example.com/...`", however the `.htaccess` you've posted explicitly redirects to the domain apex, not www?! (The rules are also in the wrong order, so the last redirect is never going to do anything!) Do you have another `.htaccess` file in one of the subdirectories? Are `/public` and `/public/home` physical directories?

Comment: Sorry, I used the previous configuration. I've just updated the code snippet. /public/ and /public/home are directories under /var/www/html/

Comment: If `/public` and `/public/home` are physical directories, where is the `.htaccess` file located? (_Aside:_ Why do you have `public` in the visible URL; shouldn't that be "hidden"?)

Comment: The .htaccess is located outside the public folder.     Yes, looking into hiding the public part in the URL.

Comment: Was able to resolve it by doing what John Hanley suggested. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved after getting an SSL certificate for both example.com and [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) after John Hanley's comment. Thanks.